# How to set super class properties when parsing JSON with gson

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

How to set super class "LookUp" properties id, name when parsing JSON array
of countries:

> ```
> [ {"ID":5, "CountryNameEN":"UK" }, {"ID":6, "CountryNameEN":"USA" }  ]
> ```

For example, When i calling get_lookups_countries() API with Retrofit 2 & parse the response with google Gson Library, I want to set super class instance members id & name with the same values of derived class "Country"

```
 @GET(Constants.LookUps.GET_COUNTRIES) Call<List<Country>> get_lookups_countries();
```

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .setLenient()
           .registerTypeAdapter(LookUp.class,new LookupsDeserializer())
           .create();

   HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
   logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
   OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .client(okHttpClient.build())
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
           .build();
   return retrofit.create(APIEndpointVatTax.class);
```

```java
public class LookUp {
    int id;
    String name;
}


public class Country extends LookUp {

        @SerializedName("ID")
        @Expose
        private Integer iD;

        @SerializedName("CountryNameEN")
        @Expose
        private String countryNameEN;
}
```

Comment: Is Lookup id and Country iD is different?

Comment: No, The same value

Comment: then why you need super class?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some issues with your JSON mappings: you're trying to bind the super class fields to the sub class fields, however this is where an interface might be a better choice for you, because your intention is just *asking* the deserialized object for its id and name.

I would do it like this:

```java
interface LookUp {

    int getId();

    String getName();

}
```

```java
final class CountryByInterface
        implements LookUp {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private final Integer id = null;

    @SerializedName("CountryNameEN")
    private final String name = null;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

So it could be used easily (Java 8 for the demo purposes only):

```java
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Type countryListType = new TypeToken<List<CountryByInterface>>() {
}.getType();
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43247712.class, "countries.json") ) {
    gson.<List<CountryByInterface>>fromJson(reader, countryListType)
            .stream()
            .map(c -> c.getId() + "=>" + c.getName())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If for some justified reason you **really** need the super class to hold such fields, you have to implement a post-processor (inspired with [PostConstructAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/PostConstructAdapterFactory.java)). Say,

```java
abstract class AbstractLookUp {

    int id;
    String name;

    abstract int getId();

    abstract String getName();

    final void postSetUp() {
        id = getId();
        name = getName();
    }

}
```

```java
final class CountryByClass
        extends AbstractLookUp {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private final Integer id = null;

    @SerializedName("CountryNameEN")
    private final String name = null;

    @Override
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                // Check if it's a class we can handle: AbstractLookUp
                if ( AbstractLookUp.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
                    // Get the downstream parser for the given type
                    final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
                    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                        @Override
                        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                                throws IOException {
                            delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                                throws IOException {
                            // Deserialize it as an AbstractLookUp instance
                            final AbstractLookUp abstractLookUp = (AbstractLookUp) delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
                            // And set it up
                            abstractLookUp.postSetUp();
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            final T result = (T) abstractLookUp;
                            return result;
                        }
                    };
                }
                return null;
            }
        })
        .create();
final Type countryListType = new TypeToken<List<CountryByClass>>() {
}.getType();
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43247712.class, "countries.json") ) {
    gson.<List<CountryByClass>>fromJson(reader, countryListType)
            .stream()
            .map(c -> ((AbstractLookUp) c).id + "=>" + ((AbstractLookUp) c).name)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Both examples produce

> 5=>UK
>   6=>USA

However I find the first approach better designed and much easier to use, whereas the second one demonstrates how Gson can be configured to implement complex (de)serialization strategies.

Comment: Best solution! Thank you Lyubomyr, You saved my time.
Thanks for support & help.